# Where can I find open APIs with wine data?

Tags: wine

I'm looking for a wine API with basic info (producer name, name, varietal, region, expert rating, description).

Wine-searcher.com has one, but it costs $350 a month and they won't give it to me temporarily (I'm just a student building a prototype app).

Anybody know of any?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is an [API](https://github.com/aptash/vivino-api) for Vivino. Although I'm not sure every information you asked for is available there.